# как обработать фото с помощью телеграмм бота не сохраняя его локально (python telegrambotapi)

Tags: python, telebot, pillow

не могу сообразить как можно обработать изображение(pillow) полученное из телеграмм с помощью бота(pytelegrambotapi), не сохраняя его локально.

```
 @bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def handle_docs_document(message):
    file_info = bot.get_file(message.photo[len(message.photo) - 1].file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
    src = 'C:/Users/мси/Desktop/bot_photo/' + message.photo[1].file_id
    with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)

    bot.reply_to(message, "Фото добавлено")

    img = Image.open(src)
    img.save('test.jpg')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=open('test.jpg', 'rb'))
bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PIL.Image.open() [принимает имя файла или файловый объект](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#functions),
Для загрузки сжатого изображения из памяти документация [советует передавать объект BytesIO](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombytes).
Если bot.download_file возвращает bytearray,
Попробуйте что-нибудь вроде

```
fp=io.BytesIO(downloaded_file)
img = Image.open(fp)
```

PS Похоже pyTelegramBotAPI [download_file](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/telebot/__init__.py#L591) [оборачивает](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/fab2b2d22387e9a72374c4caf8f595db54d6ad3a/telebot/apihelper.py#L162) requests.get().content, который как раз возвращает байты: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content

PPS
попробовал сделать

```
requests.get('http://site/bla.gif')
b=io.BytesIO(r.content)
p=PIL.Image.open(b)
p.save('test.jpg')
```

и оно свалилось потому что не может автоматически конвретировать gif в jpeg.
В зависимости от того, что вы будете делать с картинкой в pillow, обратите внимание что есть разные форматы и режимы.

PPPS второе сохранение опять можно сохранить в BytesIO,
ну или сдаться и все же использовать временные файлы: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html